# Multiple possible IVs with identical results

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a Raticate which, according to [Poké Assistant's IV calculator](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator), either has Att/Def/Sta of 8/13/11 or 14/1/11. One of these is considerably more "perfect" than the other, but they both result in identical CP and HP stats at every level.

Given there's never any difference in their CP or HP, is there actually any difference between an 8/13/11 Raticate and a 14/1/11 one?

Comment: Umm, yes? One has a better attack, and the other has a better defense. What, exactly, are you expecting?

Comment: @Ellesedil: but where does that make a difference in the game, if their CP and HP are identical?

Comment: IV's, at best, only add an additional 10% to the stat.

Comment: Is that dupe still valid? I heard they rebalanced the stats in the latest patch